# Google SignIn SDK is failing by throwing error, A non-recoverable sign in failure occurred -catch error: React Native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, google-signin

I have been trying to integrate Social login in my react native project in which I was able to do facebook login successfully but it is failing to signin to google. **react-native-google-signin** library is used for google.

The code I have used.

```
componentDidMount() {
GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices({ autoResolve: true }).then(() => {
// play services are available. can now configure library
}).catch((err) => {

console.log("Play services error", err.code, err.message);
})
GoogleSignin.configure({
scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly"], // what API you want to access on behalf of the user, default is email and profile
// iosClientId: <FROM DEVELOPER CONSOLE>, // only for iOS
webClientId: "xxx", // client ID of type WEB for your server (needed to verify user ID and offline access)
// offlineAccess: true // if you want to access Google API on behalf of the user FROM YOUR SERVER
//hostedDomain: '' // specifies a hosted domain restriction
//forceConsentPrompt: true // [Android] if you want to show the authorization prompt at each login
//accountName: '' // [Android] specifies an account name on the device that should be used
})
.then(() => {
// you can now call currentUserAsync()
});
    _signIn = async () => {

        try {

            await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices(

              )

          const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
          console.log('User Info --> ', userInfo);
          this.setState({ userInfo });
        } catch (error) {

          console.log('Message', error.message);
          if (error.code ===  statusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {
            console.log('User Cancelled the Login Flow');
          } else if (error.code === statusCodes.IN_PROGRESS) {
            console.log('Signing In');
          } else if (error.code === statusCodes.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
            console.log('Play Services Not Available or Outdated');
          } else {
            console.log('Some Other Error Happened');
          }
        }
      };
```

The error response:

```
Message: A non-recoverable sign in failure occurred -catch error
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's due to the clientId.
In google developer console, When you configure the project for webClientID, instead of creating a new project choose an existing one, i.e create the project first and then choose it for creating credentials.

Create a new project first as of in below picture
[image: create a project this way]

then choose that project from the list to create credentials [image]

It worked for me.

And coming to sign in configuration

```
GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices({ autoResolve: true }).then(() => {

})
.catch((err) => {
      console.log("Play services error", err.code, err.message);
})

GoogleSignin.configure({
     scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"],//scopes as you need 
     webClientId: "***(Your clientId)",
     //iosClientId: <FROM DEVELOPER CONSOLE>, // only for iOS 
     //offlineAccess: true, //(give it true if you need serverAuthCode i.e cross client authorisation)
     //hostedDomain: '' 
     //forceConsentPrompt: true // [Android] if you want to show the authorization prompt at each login
     //accountName: ''
})
```

Comment: Really appreciate your attempt for helping.The issue was with the mail id, I was using company mail id it got fixed when I tried with my personal account

Answer (score 38):

I know, I am very late to answer this question. I just faced the same issue and spent almost 4-5 hours to resolve this. 
The solution that I have found:
"It starts working when I have added Support Email on Firebase"
I think it's not the app or configuration issue. It may be a firebase issue that should be reported and nowhere in the doc.

[image: Screenshot for Firebase settings]

Comment: Worked for me. But I had to wait ~5minutes after adding the email.

Comment: Worked for me as well! You are the one of those life saver guys, thanks bro :)

Comment: i already have a support email added. :(

Answer (score 9):

Following [here](https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin/issues/564#issuecomment-616071930)

- cd ./android && ./gradlew signingReport
- Take the SHA1 of Task :app:signingReport, Variant: debugAndroidTest, Config: debug
- Update it the Firebase Console under Project Settings, Android app, add the SHA1
- Download the google-services.json, put it in ./android/app
- Go to Authentication, then Sign-in method, then press Google
- Take the Web client ID and use that for your GoogleSignin.configure({ webClientId: ... });
- This Web client ID should be the same as listed in https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=<your_project_id> -> Credentials -> OAuth 2 Client ID -> Web Client

Comment: thank you this completely explained all the steps.

Answer (score 9):

Apk link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FNFBX-M7PQC6ShCC3KSuOH2E57YGPj6H/view?usp=sharing

```
 go to android folder  ./gradlew signingReport Take the SHA1 of Task

 :app:signingReport, Variant: debugAndroidTest, Config: debug Update

add fingure print sha1 in your project inside firebae.console.google.com
```

and download again google-service.json file in your project

[image]

[image]

[image]

**[Error: A non-recoverable sign in failure occurred]**

```
1. add support email to solve this error 
2. and wait 5 minutes your google login will be working fine
```

[image]

Comment: Don't use your project name like googlelogin, firebase,console etc

Comment: Variant: debugAndroidTest, Config: debug Update

Answer (score 5):

run `gradlew signingReport` in the android folder and check all the **sha1** listed and if you are using firebase then make sure that all the distinct **sha1** found in the list is added to the firebase project then download the google-services.json again replace it with the old one in you project and run `cd android && gradlew clean` and build your project again

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the `support email`.
For that:-

1. Go to console.firebase.google.com
2. Select <YOUR_PROJECT> project.
3. Go to project settings
4. Under General tab scoll down to add support email. Add your email over there.

Comment: I am unable to find General Tab. Any screenshot will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I've used the package name for my test app (ex. com.loginTest). After making my package name unique, I was able to solve this problem!

Answer (score 0):

I searches and came across the following steps

> 1. Enable OAuth on `https://console.developers.google.com`
> 2. Copy and paste your SH1 while enabling
> 3. Enable Google sign in on firebase authentication
> 4. Use Oauth Client_Id instead of your WebClient ID

Answer (score 0):

This fix could also help:

1. Go to console.developer.google.com
2. Select the project.
3. Go to Credentials.
4. Switch to O Auth Consent screen.
5. Change the app name and fill email id (optional)
6. Save at the bottom

Try logging in now and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Add support email in firebase and it will start working

Answer (score 0):

### Android

Make sure to follow these guidlines:

- https://rnfirebase.io/auth/social-auth#google
- https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin/blob/master/docs/android-guide.md

Dont forget to generate SHA-Keys and set them in your Firebase Console

#### with Simulator:

When testing on an Android Simulator, make sure GooglePlayServices are enabled.
To prove this, add a few more lines to your SignInMethod:

```
const signInWithGoogle = async() => {
  // Wrap with try catch 
  try {
    await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices({ showPlayServicesUpdateDialog: true }); // <-- Add this
    const { idToken } = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
    const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken);
    return auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential);
  } catch (error) {
    // This will show you if GooglePlayServices is missing
    console.log('With high probability, GooglePlayServices are missing on this device');
    return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem can reside in the app name, change it to a random (or unique) one (a name you're sure nobody else chosen), or generate a new app with a random (or unique) name.

This is because the generated React Native apps come all with the same SHA-1 fingerprint, and because Google prevents that two different Android apps registered on their cloud share the same pair of App name and SHA-1 fingerprint, you got this error (and surely you have already seen a warning on the Firebase console when creating the App!).

Source: https://support.googles.ltd/firebase/answer/6401008?hl=en&ref_topic=6399725

A complete guide to use Google signin on a React Native app: https://github.com/ubugnu/reactnative-google-signin

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why but i got this error on emulator with Android 28
when i create another emulator with api 31 the error fixed!

Answer (score 0):

**IF YOUR APP ARE ON RELEASE:**

- On project, go to `/android`, then run `./gradlew signingReport`
- Copy SHA1 of release and debugTest (very important)
- Go to https://console.firebase.google.com
- Place all SHA1
- Download Google Services JSON and put it on `android/app`
- Build your app and run!

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same issue for over a day.

This is whats causing the problem
If you Open your android studio and open project, goto your expo/react native "android" folder and click the project,
After build,

1. On the right hand side you will see **gradle**, along with other options, its a vertical bar with the gradle button text rotated 90deg. Click it, a tab on the right shows, you will see a little mouse image along with other options, click it and a tab will show afterwards.
2. the tab shows gradle and an input to type something, type in: `signingreport`
3. click enter, and you will see the SHA-1 fingerprint, just copy the first one when you scroll up,
4. Goto google console and use that SHA-1 to create your android credentials, copy the android client id given,
5. Goto android/app/src/main/res/values/string.xml
6. Paste this in the list:

```html
<string name="server_client_id">YOUR_GOOGLE_ANDROID_CLIENT_ID</string>
```

7. In your eas.json, make sure credentialSource is pointing to local, here is a sample

```js
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 5.4.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk",
        "credentialsSource": "local"
      },
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk",
        "credentialsSource": "local"
      },
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk",
        "credentialsSource": "local"
      }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

8. Create  `credentials.json` file and add this

```js
   {
  "android": {
    "keystore": {
      "keystorePath": "./android/app/debug.keystore",
      "keystorePassword": "android",
      "keyAlias": "androiddebugkey",
      "keyPassword": "android"
    }
  },
}
```

Then run one of the profile from `eas.json`  i.e

```
npx expo prebuild && eas build --profile preview --platform android --local
```

This generates an apk for preview, you can use

```
npx expo prebuild && eas build --profile development --platform android --local
```

For a development build you can get incremental update while working locally on your computer.

The issue you are facing is that expo uses debug.keystore to sign your app, as you would have see in the android studio `signingreport`. To use a release.keystore or any other, `Variant: release` from signingreport and other package seen in that report need to be configured to use the `release.keystore`. You can do a google search on how to do that.