# Google login without firebase is not working in react native

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-google-login

I'm trying to implement google login without firebase in react-native. here i have generated Client ID and Client secret from google cloud and also added required dependency but still the state is not loaded and not showing any content.

I received this error in console: A non-recoverable sign in failure occurred

please help me if anyone is having idea about it

Thanks in advance!!

[image: build.gradle]

[image: settings.gradle]
[image: UI_Image]

```js
import {Text, View, Image} from 'react-native';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {GoogleSignin, statusCodes} from '@react-native-community/google-signin';
import {GoogleSigninButton} from '@react-native-community/google-signin';

export class GoogleLogin extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
     userGoogleInfo: {},
     loaded: false,
     };
    }

  componentDidMount() {
  GoogleSignin.configure({
  webClientId:
    'my Web client id',
  offlineAccess: true,
  });
  }
  signIn = async () => {
  try {
  await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
  const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
  this.setState({
    userGoogleInfo: userInfo,
    loaded: true,
  });
  console.log(this.state.userGoogleInfo);
} catch (error) {
  if (error.code === statusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {
    console.log('e 1');
  } else if (error.code === statusCodes.IN_PROGRESS) {
    console.log('e 2');
  } else if (error.code === statusCodes.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
    console.log('e 3');
  } else {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
  }
  };
    
  render() {
  return (
  <View>
    <GoogleSigninButton
      onPress={this.signIn}
      size={GoogleSigninButton.Size.Wide}
      color={GoogleSigninButton.Color.Dark}
      style={{width: '100%', height: 100}}
    />

    {this.state.loaded ? (
      <View>
        <Text> {this.state.userGoogleInfo.dictionary}</Text>
        console.log('Hello')
      </View>
    ) : (
      <Text> Not sign in</Text>
    )}
  </View>
);
}
}
export default GoogleLogin;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google SignIn SDK is failing by throwing error, A non-recoverable sign in failure occurred -catch error: React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53816227/google-signin-sdk-is-failing-by-throwing-error-a-non-recoverable-sign-in-failur)

Comment: I have seen this one and tried, but without firebase it can't solved.

Comment: @DhyanaDave you need to add your configuration detail fill in  the below link like SHA-1 key, package ID, Domain detail, etc.

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent/edit


For more information you also check this blog
https://dev.to/suyashvash/google-authsignin-in-react-native-without-firebase-43n